# Karate UI button click support

Tags: karate

I was unable to click the button(submit my request);

My button was placed in the table:

```
<tr>
<td>
<input id ="test" type= "button" value ="test"
onClick=opentest();
</td>
</tr>
```

**I have used the following way to click the button :**

**When submit().click('input[name=test]')
 **

I was unable to click is there is any other way to click the button as my button field is stored in table
Can some body helpus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mouse('#foo').click()`

Else please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Hi peter actually showing success but the button is not actually clicked, so the next steps fail. we have also added delay and screenshot to verify the same.we have tried submit().click('input[name=test],mouse('#tes't).click(), but we dindt able to click it.

Comment: Here we are using 0.9.5 version Following code i have used for this test.Given driver 'https:launch/test.html' And input('#test1', 'test') And input('#test2', 'test') And input('#test3', 'test') When submit().click('input[name=test]') * delay(1000).screenshot()

Comment: @vishnuvardhan try 0.9.6.RC3 else I have no other solution for you except to follow the process. all the best

Comment: Thanks peter!I have used  click('#test'), i was able to open it

Comment: Hi Peter can you please suggest how to check the radio button box, i was unable figure it out

Comment: @vishnuvardhan sorry since you can't follow the process, please wait for someone else who has more patience than me :)

Comment: apologizes for that Thomas.