# Events such as click is not working on UI5 with Karate UI testing

Tags: sapui5, karate

On SAP UI5, after rendering when I try to call any components such as button's using its ID and perform any events like click is not working from Karate.

```
click("[id='ValidationGroup::LineItem::StandardAction::Create']")   -> didn't work
```

```
focus("[id='ValidationGroup::LineItem::StandardAction::Create']")   -> works
```

Will there be any other way to make it work?

---

**
Check these below images for more clarifications.**

[Create button which works for focus but not working for clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLZba.png)

[HTML component value of the button Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h2PE.png))

---

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: read this please and edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your locators may be wrong. It may not be possible for others to help without direct access to your app.

You can try `mouse()` which may work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62407468/143475